# CDCACMでUSB Bulk転送したい

Tags: spresense

カーネルコンフィグで、
USB Modem (CDC/ACM) support　✔︎CDCACM　とデフォルトでチェックされてると思います

**USB Bulk転送／受信するサンプルとかありませんでしょうか**

■環境　Spresense SDK　1.5.1

---

続きのカーネルコンフィグでできそうな雰囲気がプンプンするのですが、ソフトの書き方がよくわかりません

> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Endpoint 0 max packet size 64 CDCACM_EP0MAXPACKET
>
> Endpoint 0 max packet size. Default 64.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Interrupt IN endpoint number 6 CDCACM_EPINTIN
>
> The logical 7-bit address of a hardware endpoint that supports
>   interrupt IN operation. Default 1.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Interupt IN full speed MAXPACKET size 64 CDCACM_EPINTIN_FSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the interrupt IN endpoint if full speed mode.
>   Default 64.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Interupt IN high speed MAXPACKET size 64 CDCACM_EPINTIN_HSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the interrupt IN endpoint if high speed mode.
>   Default 64.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk OUT endpoint number 5 CDCACM_EPBULKOUT
>
> The logical 7-bit address of a hardware endpoint that supports bulk
>   OUT operation. Default: 3
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk OUT full speed MAXPACKET size 64 CDCACM_EPBULKOUT_FSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the bulk OUT endpoint if full speed mode. Default
>   64.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk OUT out high speed MAXPACKET size 512 CDCACM_EPBULKOUT_HSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the bulk OUT endpoint if high speed mode. Default
>   512.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk IN endpoint number 4 CDCACM_EPBULKIN
>
> The logical 7-bit address of a hardware endpoint that supports bulk IN
>   operation. Default: 2
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk IN full speed MAXPACKET size 64 CDCACM_EPBULKIN_FSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the bulk IN endpoint if full speed mode. Default
>   64.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Bulk IN high speed MAXPACKET size 512 CDCACM_EPBULKIN_HSSIZE
>
> Max package size for the bulk IN endpoint if high speed mode. Default
>   512.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Number of read requests that can be in flight 4 CDCACM_NRDREQS
>
> The number of read requests that can be in flight
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Number of write requests that can be in flight 4 CDCACM_NWRREQS
>
> The number of write/read requests that can be in flight
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Size of one write request buffer 768 CDCACM_BULKIN_REQLEN
>
> Ideally, the BULKOUT request size should *not* be the same size as the
>   maxpacket size. That is because IN transfers of exactly the maxpacket
>   size will be followed by a NULL packet. The BULKOUT, on the other
>   hand, request buffer size is always the same as the maxpacket size.
>
> There is also no reason from CDCACM_BULKIN_REQLEN to be greater than
>   CDCACM_TXBUFSIZE-1, since a request larger than the TX buffer can
>   never be sent.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Receive buffer size 3080 CDCACM_RXBUFSIZE
>
> Size of the serial receive buffers. The actual amount of data that can
>   be held in the buffer is this number minus one due to the way that the
>   circular buffer is managed. So an RX buffer size of 257 will hold four
>   full-speed, 64 byte packets; a buffer size of 513 will hold one
>   high-speed, 512 byte packet.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Transmit buffer size 769 CDCACM_TXBUFSIZE
>
> Size of the serial transmit buffers. The actual amount of data that
>   can be held in the buffer is this number minus one due to the way that
>   the circular buffer is managed. So a TX buffer size of 769 will hold
>   one request of size 768; a buffer size of 193 will hold two requests
>   of size 96 bytes.
>
> Depends on: CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Vendor ID 0x054c CDCACM_VENDORID
>
> The vendor ID code/string. Default 0x0525 and "NuttX" 0x0525 is the
>   Netchip vendor and should not be used in any products. This default
>   VID was selected for compatibility with the Linux CDC ACM default VID.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Product ID 0x0bc2 CDCACM_PRODUCTID
>
> The product ID code/string. Default 0xa4a7 and "CDC/ACM Serial" 0xa4a7
>   was selected for compatibility with the Linux CDC ACM default PID.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Vendor string SONY CDCACM_VENDORSTR
>
> There is no help available for this option.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV
>
> Device Drivers ➤ USB Device Driver Support ➤ USB Modem (CDC/ACM)
>   support
>
> Product string CDC/ACM Serial CDCACM_PRODUCTSTR
>
> There is no help available for this option.
>
> Depends on: !CDCACM_COMPOSITE && CDCACM && USBDEV

Comment: spresense-nuttxのgithubで[spresense-nuttx/drivers/usbdev/cdcacm.c](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/blob/master/drivers/usbdev/cdcacm.c)とか、検索結果[Search - bulk 103 code results in sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense-nuttx/search?q=bulk&unscoped_q=bulk)とか有るようですが、これらを元に何か進展しますか？

Answer (score 0):

SDKチュートリアルが参考になると思います。
https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_tutorials_ja.html#_system_cdcacm
この通りに設定すれば、拡張ボード側のUSBが新たなCOMポートとしてPC上に認識されると思います。
Spresenseソースコードからは/dev/ttyACM0 をopenしてread/writeすることでPCと通信できてます。

あと、Spresense Arduino環境でのUSBSerialライブラリというものも見つけました。
https://qiita.com/baggio/items/e62cb26630fdb78881f2
これも中身は/dev/ttyACM0に対してread/writeを行っているみたいです。